# Boto3 (and AWS CLI) only returns 25 API Gateway custom domains when web GUI shows more

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, boto3, aws-cli

I can only imagine I'm doing something stupid here, but I can't figure out what. The AWS GUI shows .. well, lots of custom domains that I've set up. Eyeballing it, I'd estimate 75 or so. When I query via either the Boto3 library or the AWS CLI, it steadfastly returns 25 (no errors) and no more. I've tried the following using Boto3:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(region_name="eu-west-1")
apigw = session.client('apigatewayv2')
print(apigw.get_domain_names()["Items"]) # Returns 25 items
print(apigw.get_domain_names(MaxResults="1000")["Items"]) # Also returns 25 items
```

Similarly, I've tried the following calls using the CLI:

`aws apigatewayv2 get-domain-names`

`aws apigatewayv2 get-domain-names --max-items=1000`

To be clear, I **definitely** have more than 25 domain names set up in this account's API Gateway. I've double and triple checked that.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong in calling the service?

Comment: You are using `apigatewayv2`, but `apigateway` also has `get-domain-names`. Have you tried with `apigateway`?

Answer (score 0):

Many boto3 client api calls have a built-in limit, and you are likely hitting this.  Sometimes those limits are not documented.  If you want to pull back *all* items, you should use a paginator. If a function has a corresponding paginator, that is a sure sign that the client call has a limit.  You can use tokens to paginate through things yourself with a client, but a paginator does this for you and is usually a better way to go.

Here's the [paginator syntax for this same call](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigatewayv2.html#ApiGatewayV2.Paginator.GetDomainNames):

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('get_domain_names')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    PaginationConfig={
        'MaxItems': 123,
        'PageSize': 123,
        'StartingToken': 'string'
    }
)
```

You probably just want to call

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('get_domain_names')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate()
```

It seems wrong that MaxResults would not return up to the number you specify, but check out the discussion in [this post](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2053), which may not be official, but still helps explain the behavior:

> The maxResults is the maximum number of items to return for this
> request. It can happen that you may get less than the specified value.
> It only guarantees that you will not have more than 100 results. If
> you are not getting all results then you will get a nextToken to make
> another api call.